# Read a key file extension into bytes using c# and pass it to encryption algorithm

Tags: c#, rijndael

I am using a binary reader to read my .key file. output i am getting is 37 byte array. But my specified algorithm need to have only 16 bytes.I am getting "specified key size is not valid for this algorithm" error when I pass parameter to encryption algorithm(Rijindael managed class used for encryption). The Key file and algorithm suggested by client.

Code for converting .key file to bytes is

```
public static byte[] ConvertFileToByteArray(string fileName)
{
    byte[] returnValue = null;
    using (FileStream fr = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fr))
        {
            returnValue = br.ReadBytes((int)fr.Length);

        }
    }       
    return returnValue;
}
```

Encryption algorithm is (the block and keysize mentioned below is equal to 16 bytes or 128 bits)

```
'  static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{      
    if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
    byte[] encrypted;       
    using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijAlg.BlockSize = 0x80;
        rijAlg.KeySize = 0x80;
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.GenerateIV();
        rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);         
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {                        
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }       
    return encrypted;
}
```

'

Comment: Not the answer, but the first function can be replaced by `byte[] keyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("yourKeyFile");`, and for the key site, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalkeysizes(v=vs.110).aspx) say it must <= 32 bytes. You don't have any choice but use other keyfile or use a subrange of the file or change encrypt method.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write the length in the msEncrypt as follows:

```
    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // prepend the IV
        msEncrypt.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
        msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);
        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
            {
                //Write all data to the stream.
                swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
            }
        }
        outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
    }
```

if it is still doesn't work, it's probably due to a faulty initialization of your "rijAlg" element.
try to take a look at:
[decrpyt .Net Encrypted string in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24048306/1447518)
which has a working encryption which had worked for me.